# Crear array a partir de un formulario

Tags: php, laravel, formularios

mi problema es el siguiente, tengo una vista donde en base a un numero de edificios desplego un numero de inputs para cargar datos respectivos a cada edificio, este numero de edificios lo guardo en la variable, $numeroedificios que luego hago interar con un for de la siguiente manera en mi **vista**

```
   @for($i = 0; $i < $numeroedificios  ; $i++  )


<input type="text"  title="Nombre de edificio" class="form-control " name="nombreedificio[]"   id="nombreedificio[]         "   placeholder="Nombre de edificio"  required />

<input type="number"  title="Numero de aulas" class="form-control"  min="1" max="32" 
name="numeroaulas[]"   id="numeroaulas[]"   placeholder="Numero de Aulas" required />

<input type="text"  title="Prefijo aula" class="form-control " name="prefijoaulas[]"  onkeyup="myFunction()"    id="prefijoaulas[]"   placeholder="Prefijo de aulas"  required />
```

Datos que deben llegar en un array a mi **controlador** estos datos los recibo en un array de la siguiente manera

```
    $edificios = array(

'nombreedificio' => $request->nombreedificio,
'numeroaulas' => $request->numeroaulas,
'prefijoaulas' => $request->prefijoaulas,


);

dd($edificios);
```

Al ejecutar un dd($edificios ) puedo observar lo siguiente

[image: CAPTURA DE PANTALLA RESULTADO DE dd($edificios):]

Lo que quiero es poder interar todos los registros ingresados basados en los numeros de  edificios, y poder guardarlos de forma ordenada para enviarlos a la vista de nuevo para que el usuario pueda verificar los datos ingresados y guardalos. Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: No entiendo... quieres *iterar **para guardarlos** de forma ordenada **para enviarlos** a la vista **de nuevo para** que el usuario pueda **verificar** los datos ingresados y **guardarlos***. ¿No quieres hacer una y otra vez la misma cosa con esos datos? No entiendo por qué hay que manipular tanto a ese pobre array, ¿no habrá un problema de lógica en la concepción de tu programa?

Comment: olvida el enviarlos a la vista, solo guardarlos en la base de datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calcula el número de elementos que tiene el primer índice (por ejemplo), ya que se presupone que los demás tendrán el mismo número, y a partir de ahí, itera y extrae los elementos:

```
<?php
    $countEdificios = count($edificios['nombreedificio']);

    for($i = 0; $i < $countEdificios; $i++) {

      $thisNombreEdificio = $edicifios['nombreedificio'][$i];
      $thisNumeroAulas = $edicifios['numeroaulas'][$i];
      $thisPrefijoAula = $edificios['prefijoaulas'][$i];

      // Guardar en base de datos.

    }
```

Comment: El conteo de los edificios no se guarda en $countedificios, me sale error de variable no definida

Comment: amigo verifique y realice unas pruebas tu solucion es la correcta muchisimas gracias