# ingresar datos con array PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, bootstrap

Tengo una tabla con un form para que me muestre de un lado los usuarios registrados y del otro los input de cada uno a llenar pero a la hora de llenar los datos me da error. Acá les dejo formulario. Es la solución que me pasaron. Estaré pendiente para responder lo mas rápido posible

```
 <form method="POST">

        <table class="table table-striped table-sm  table-bordered table-hover">
        <div class="col-3">
            <label for="fechaAporte"><h3><b>Fecha del Aporte</b></h3></label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fechaAporte" required>
        </div>
        <br>
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>Cedula</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>apellido</th>

                    <th>Aporte Asociado</th>
                    <th>Fecha Pago del Asociado</th>
                    <th>Aporte Patronal</th>
                    <th>Fecha del Aporte Patronal</th>
                    <th>Total del Monto Aportado</th>
                    <th>Acción</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php                
                $resultadoBus = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM asociado WHERE tipoUsuario = 2");

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadoBus)) { 

                    ?>
                    <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['cedula']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['apellido']; ?></td>
                  <!-- while de Haberes -->
                    <td><input type="number" name="aporteAsociado[]" class="form-control" id="aporte1" ></td>
                    <td><input type="date" name="fechaPagoAsociado[]" class="form-control" id="fechaPagoAsociado" ></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="aportePatrono[]" class="form-control" id="aporte2"></td>
                    <td><input type="date" name="fechaAportePatrono[]" class="form-control" id="fechaAportePatrono"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="montoAporte[]" class="form-control" id="total"></td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="cedulaArray" value="<?php echo $row['cedula']; ?>">


                    <td>

                        <button type="submit" name="btnCrearHaber" class="btn btn-success">Registrar Aporte</button>

                    </td>


                    <tr>
                <?php } ?>

            </tbody>

</table>    

 </form>
```

Y acá el PHP para guardar los datos, me imagino que es el que me está dando fallos en la parte lógica, intenté darle con estos arrays usando una variable para recorrer pero no me guarda nada en la base de datos

```
  if (!empty($_POST)){

    if(isset($_POST['btnCrearHaber'])) {

        $contadorHaber = count($_POST['cedulaArray']);

        for($i = 0; $i<$contadorHaber; $i++){

        $cedulaAsociado = $_POST['cedulaArray'] [$i];
        $fechaAporte = $_POST['fechaAporte'] [$i];
        $aporteAsociado = $_POST['aporteAsociado'] [$i];
        $fechaPagoAsociado = $_POST['fechaPagoAsociado'] [$i];
        $aportePatrono = $_POST['aportePatrono'] [$i];
        $fechaAportePatrono = $_POST['fechaAportePatrono'] [$i];
        $montoAporte = $_POST['montoAporte'] [$i];
        $estado = 0;
        $insertando = "INSERT INTO haber (cedulaAsociado, fechaAporte , aporteAsociado, fechaPagoAsociado, aportePatrono, fechaAportePatrono, montoAporte, estado)
                                VALUES ('$cedulaAsociado', '$fechaAporte', '$aporteAsociado', '$fechaPagoAsociado', '$aportePatrono', '$fechaAportePatrono', '$montoAporte', '$estado')";

        $resultado =  mysqli_query($mysqli, $insertando);
        }
```

Comment: En cada iteración del ciclo creas todos los campos con el mismo nombre y, por supuesto, el navegador tratará de decidir cuál es el que debe enviar. Intenta crearlos como array: `<input name="nombre_campo[]">`

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Crear array a partir de un formulario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/112669/crear-array-a-partir-de-un-formulario)

Comment: y cuando reciba en el php sería con array igual, no?

Comment: ¡Es correcto, sí, señor!

Comment: Bueno, intenté y bien pero en el sql no sé como colocarlo

Comment: Revisa el ejemplo que te puse en el segundo comentario, trata de aplicarlo y, si no funciona, edita tu pregunta para poner el nuevo código y ayudarte a partir de ahí.

Comment: Ya edité, es la solución que estaba en la página que pasaste pero no funcionó

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#bueno no entiendo por que lo pones como array no hay ningun problema usando el mismo 
 #nombre(te recomendaria ordenar tu codigo)


 #IMPORTANTE $MySQLiconn es la variable de conexion a la bd
  #CODIGO PARA LA CONEXION
 define('_HOST_NAME','localhost');
 define('_DATABASE_NAME','ACA COLOCAS EL NOMBRE DE TU BASE DE DATOS');
 define('_DATABASE_USER_NAME','TU USUARIO POR LO GENERAL ES root');
 define('_DATABASE_PASSWORD','COLOCAS CONTRASEÑA SI COLOCASTE ALGUNA');

 $MySQLiconn = new 
 MySQLi(_HOST_NAME,_DATABASE_USER_NAME,_DATABASE_PASSWORD,_DATABASE_NAME);


 if($MySQLiconn->connect_errno)
 {
     die("ERROR : -> ".$MySQLiconn->connect_error);
 }


if(isset($_POST['save']))
{

 $fn = $MySQLiconn->real_escape_string($_POST['fn']);
 $ln = $MySQLiconn->real_escape_string($_POST['ln']);

 $SQL = $MySQLiconn->query("INSERT INTO data(fn,ln) VALUES('$fn','$ln')");

 if(!$SQL)
 {
     echo $MySQLiconn->error;
 } 
}
#EL CODIGO QUE TIENES QUE AGREGAR $MySQLiconn->real_escape_string
```

## QUITALE LAS LLAVES NO ES NECESARIO

```
                <td><input type="number" name="aporteAsociado" class="form-control" id="aporte1" ></td>
                <td><input type="date" name="fechaPagoAsociado" class="form-control" id="fechaPagoAsociado" ></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="aportePatrono" class="form-control" id="aporte2"></td>
                <td><input type="date" name="fechaAportePatrono" class="form-control" id="fechaAportePatrono"></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="montoAporte" class="form-control" id="total"></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="cedulaArray" value="<?php echo $row['cedula']; ?>">
```

Comment: Eso lo vi en otro lado y al chico le funcionó, quizás no era mi solución. intentaré con tu método, gracias

Comment: Gracias amigo, me funcionó pero no hay una forma de optimizarlo? osea, que en lugar de darle click en enviar uno a uno se envíe todo de una vez con un botón?

Comment: no entiendo tu duda al dar click en  enviar se envía todos tus datos del formulario.

Answer (score 0):

Te comento que el que parece ser tu error empieza desde el formulario, te recomiendo que no trates de mandar toda la información de un solo golpe, eso solo va a hacer mas complicado tu codigo de

```
<table class="table table-striped table-sm  table-bordered table-hover">
        <div class="col-3">
            <label for="fechaAporte"><h3><b>Fecha del Aporte</b></h3></label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fechaAporte" required>
        </div>
        <br>
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>Cedula</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>apellido</th>

                    <th>Aporte Asociado</th>
                    <th>Fecha Pago del Asociado</th>
                    <th>Aporte Patronal</th>
                    <th>Fecha del Aporte Patronal</th>
                    <th>Total del Monto Aportado</th>
                    <th>Acción</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php                
                $resultadoBus = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM asociado WHERE tipoUsuario = 2");

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadoBus)) { 
                    ?>
                    <form method="POST" action="someController.php">
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['cedula']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['apellido']; ?></td>
                        <!-- while de Haberes -->
                            <td><input type="number" name="aporteAsociado" class="form-control" id="aporte1" ></td>
                            <td><input type="date" name="fechaPagoAsociado" class="form-control" id="fechaPagoAsociado" ></td>
                            <td><input type="number" name="aportePatrono" class="form-control" id="aporte2"></td>
                            <td><input type="date" name="fechaAportePatrono" class="form-control" id="fechaAportePatrono"></td>
                            <td><input type="number" name="montoAporte" class="form-control" id="total"></td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="cedula" value="<?php echo $row['cedula']; ?>">


                            <td>

                                <button type="submit" name="btnCrearHaber" class="btn btn-success">Registrar Aporte</button>

                            </td>


                        </tr>
                    </form>
                <?php } ?>

            </tbody>

</table>
```

A nivel grafico esto no va acambiar como es que tu ves los datos, pero a nivel logico va a hacer todo mucho mas sencillo, de aqui lo unico que debes hacer es pasar al backend todos tus datos e interpretarlos, debiendo quedar algo como

```
if(isset($_POST['cedula'])&& $_POST["cedula"] != NULL) {

    $cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
    $fechaAporte = $_POST['fechaAporte'];
    $aporteAsociado = $_POST['aporteAsociado'];
    $fechaPagoAsociado = $_POST['fechaPagoAsociado'];
    $aportePatrono = $_POST['aportePatrono'];
    $fechaAportePatrono = $_POST['fechaAportePatrono'];
    $montoAporte = $_POST['montoAporte'];
    $estado = 0;
    $insertando = "INSERT INTO haber (cedulaAsociado, fechaAporte , aporteAsociado, fechaPagoAsociado, aportePatrono, fechaAportePatrono, montoAporte, estado)
                            VALUES ('$cedulaAsociado', '$fechaAporte', '$aporteAsociado', '$fechaPagoAsociado', '$aportePatrono', '$fechaAportePatrono', '$montoAporte', '$estado')";

    $resultado =  mysqli_query($mysqli, $insertando);
    /*SOME VALIDATION*/   
}
```

De esta manera tienes mas control sobre todo lo que entra a tu sistema.